# BlogNew command in the Vimrepress addon not recognizing | as a delimiter between two commands

Tags: vim

This is what I tried to do:

```
vi +"BlogNew post | w /tmp/xxx.html"
```

I got the following message:

```
Erreur détectée en traitant command line :
Invalid option: post | w /tmp/xxx.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlogNew does not accept `|` as a delimiter (as it is not defined with `-bar`).

Instead you could pass it as two commands instead.

```
vim +"BlogNew post" +"w /tmp/xxx.html"
```

Comment: Right. Or use `+"execute 'BlogNew post' | w /tmp/xxx.html"` (just for completeness, I would also prefer yours).